# How to write ALU control lines?

Tags: cpu-architecture, digital-logic, alu

I know logical ADD in binary is 0010, and logical AND in binary is 0000. How do I go from this to a full operation?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The diagram has an error with the a-> green arrow extending too far, going right past the inverter; it should look like the b-> green arrow instead, which stops at the inverter and becomes black post inverter.

Answer (score 2):

There's two control lines: `Ainvert`, and `Bnegate`, which can be used to invert values before combining them.

Use them as needed!

The `Bnegate` control line does these two things:

- inverts the bits of the `b` input to `~b`, which is then fed to the other circuits as the `b`-side/lower input.
- and also feeds a 1 into the carry input of the adder, `+`.

The combined effect of `Bnegate` with the `+`  `Operation`, will accomplish `a + ~b + 1`, which is the same as `a-b` and also `a + -b`, because in two's complement, -x = ~x+1.

Though we can, we don't *have* to use the `+` with `Bnegate`, as others operations are still available.

---

Given this logic diagram, what are some things that cannot be done?

- `a + ~b`  (though `~a + b` can be done)
- `a | -b`
- `a & -b`
- `-a + b`